# How to detect QR code using python and pyzbar

Tags: python-3.x, qr-code, opencv, python

So i have this QR code which pyzbar is unable to detect.
QR code :
[image]

Below is the Code that I have been using for detection :

```
# import the necessary packages
from pyzbar import pyzbar

import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
##
##ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
##ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,help="path to input image")
##args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the input image
image = cv2.imread("D:\\QrReaderOutput\\thresh.png")





# find the barcodes in the image and decode each of the barcodes
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)

print(barcodes)

# loop over the detected barcodes
for barcode in barcodes:
    # extract the bounding box location of the barcode and draw the
    # bounding box surrounding the barcode on the image
    print("found")
    (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
    img = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
    # the barcode data is a bytes object so if we want to draw it on
    # our output image we need to convert it to a string first
    barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
    barcodeType = barcode.type
    
    # draw the barcode data and barcode type on the image
    text = "{} ({})".format(barcodeData, barcodeType)
    cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    # print the barcode type and data to the terminal
    print("[INFO] Found {} barcode: {}".format(barcodeType, barcodeData))
# show the output image
cv2.imwrite("D:\QrReaderOutput\outimg-1.png", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can you please help me to understand why it is failing to detect this QR code , from a random QR scanner app, I am able to decode this QR code.

Thank you.

Comment: Try cv2's qr code decoder instead of this...

Comment: okk.. I will see and update here.

Comment: Hi , sorry for the really late reply. 

I did try to scan the above image using the following code :


`import cv2

# Name of the QR Code Image file
filename = "F:\\ProgramInputs\\Scanned_Invoice\\qr_vadilal.png"
# read the QRCODE image
image = cv2.imread(filename)
# initialize the cv2 QRCode detector
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
# detect and decode
data, vertices_array, binary_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(image)
# if there is a QR code
# print the data
if vertices_array is not None:
  print("QRCode data:")
  print(data)
else:
  print("There was some error") `

Comment: and the output was "There was some error". Is there any preprocessing of images i have to do before getting this working?

Comment: what is the value in your qr code actually? do u have the desired output or something like that? i tried to decode your qr code, i didn't get any value too

Comment: so it gives a base64 output. the thing is, there are some websites like docparser, where we can crop the qr code and share it with them for decoding. this same qr code is working there. so I am think how is it possible to get the working there and not here.

Comment: so is it an image from a pdf?

Comment: Hi , sorry for late reply. Yes, it is a image from a pdf. it is a scanned image of a  pdf.

Comment: what program are u using to extract images from the pdf? is it some python module or an online tool? or do u convert a whole page as an image or something like that?

Comment: so the actual pdf was scanned using mobile scanner, and the image was send to me, since the whole image was not getting scanned properly, so I snipped the qr part only. I snipped it using windows snippet app.

Comment: any mistake I am doing? i there anything else that works better in other programming language? js or anything? I though python had the best image reading libs so i went for it.

Comment: so u r getting your expected output when u scan the qr code in the docparser right? why wouldn't u use that? i tried something to decode the qr code, but still got no results

Comment: docparser is a paid product actually. Ok no problem, I will look into other stuffs and see If i can get this thing working. Thanks